# Fluid simulation : domain appears opaque when render

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a simple fluid animation and it works well as far as I don't try to render it. In render mode, or if I try to render the animation, the domain becomes opaque. In other modes, the scene is correctly displayed and fluid particles are correctly animated and visible.
What can be the cause of the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the *Mesh* option, otherwise it won't convert the simulation into mesh:

[image]

Comment: Had to bake the simulation for this solution to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes you may need to refresh the bake